# Ising model has short range correlation (Exercise in Velenik's book)

Tags: statistical-mechanics, correlation-functions, ising-model, lattice-model

I'm studying the book "Statistical mechanics of lattice systems" by Sacha Freidli and Yvan Velenik, exercise 3.15 page 109:

Let $\beta\geq 0$ and $h\in\mathbb{R}$, show that $\langle\cdot\rangle^+_{\beta,h}$ has short range correlations, in the sense that, for all local functions $f$ and $g$,

$$\lim_{||i||_1\rightarrow\infty}\langle f\cdot(g\cdot\theta_i)\rangle^+_{\beta,h}=\langle f\rangle^+_{\beta,h}\langle g\rangle^+_{\beta,h}.$$ By linearity, we may asume $f=n_A, g=n_B$ for some finite subsets $A,B$ of $\mathbb{Z}^d$.

Here the notation $\langle\cdot\rangle^+_{\beta,h}$ is explained on page 100, theorem 3.17, and local functions are functinos of $\mathbb{Z}^d$ that depend only on finitely many lattice points.

I'm very confused by the solution given in the appendix on page 567. First By the FKG inequality we have $$\liminf_{||i||_1\rightarrow\infty}\langle f\cdot(g\cdot\theta_i)\rangle^+_{\beta,h}\geq\langle f\rangle^+_{\beta,h}\langle g\rangle^+_{\beta,h}.$$

To prove the other direction, the book argues that we fix $L$ large enough to ensure that $A,B\subset B(L)$. Taking $||i||_1$ sufficiently large, we can guarantee that $B(L+1)\cap(i+B(L))=\varnothing$. Fixing all the spins on $\partial^{ex}B(L)\cup\partial^{ex}(i+B(L))$ to $+1$, it follows from the FKG inequality that

$$\langle n_An_{B+i}\rangle^+_{\beta,h} \boxed{\leq} \langle n_A\rangle^+_{B(L);\beta,h}\langle n_{B+i}\rangle^+_{i+B(L);\beta,h}=\langle n_A\rangle^+_{B(L),\beta,h}\langle n_B\rangle^+_{B(L),\beta,h}$$ from here we have the other direction.

My question is: how do we get the boxed inequality above from the FKG inequality? This looks like reversed? Furthermore, doesn't the FKG inequality require the domains to be identical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe first that $f = n_An_{B+i}$ is a nondecreasing function.
Observe also that the same is true of the indicator function $g$ of the event $\{\forall i\in \partial^{\rm ex} B(L) \cup \partial^{\rm ex} (i+B(L)), \sigma_i=1\}$. Therefore, FKG yields
$$
\langle fg \rangle_{\beta,h}^+ \geq \langle f \rangle_{\beta,h}^+ \langle g \rangle_{\beta,h}^+
$$
and thus
$$
\frac{\langle fg \rangle_{\beta,h}^+}{\langle g \rangle_{\beta,h}^+} \geq \langle f \rangle_{\beta,h}^+.
\tag{1}
$$
Note that
$$
\frac{\langle f g\rangle_{\beta,h}^+}{\langle g\rangle_{\beta,h}^+}
=
\langle f \rangle_{\Delta;\beta,h}^+,
$$
where the latter expectation is taken in the set $\Delta = \mathbb{Z}^d\setminus (\partial^{\rm ex} B(L) \cup \partial^{\rm ex} (i+B(L)))$, with $+$ boundary condition along $\partial^{\rm ex} B(L) \cup \partial^{\rm ex} (i+B(L))$.

Remember that $f= n_An_{B+i}$.
By the spatial Markov property and the fact that the supports of $n_A$ and $n_{B+i}$ lie respectively in $B(L)$ and $B(L)+i$, it follows that
$$
\langle f \rangle_{\Delta;\beta,h}^+ = \langle n_A \rangle_{B(L);\beta,h}^+ \langle n_{B+i} \rangle_{B(L)+i;\beta,h}^+.
$$
Finally, by translation invariance of the $+$-state,
$$
\langle n_{B+i} \rangle_{B(L)+i;\beta,h}^+ = \langle n_{B} \rangle_{B(L);\beta,h}^+.
$$
Putting all this together, (1) becomes
$$
\langle n_A \rangle_{B(L);\beta,h}^+ \langle n_{B} \rangle_{B(L);\beta,h}^+ \geq \langle n_An_{B+i} \rangle_{\beta,h}^+,
$$
which is the desired inequality.

Comment: I wrote this a bit quickly, tell me if there are things that are unclear. I should have time to update my answer later this afternoon, if needed.

Comment: Hello professor Velenik! Can we also say: whenever $i$ is large enough that $A$ and $i+B$ are sufficiently seperated, and if $B(L)$ contains both $A$ and $B+i$, then $\langle n_An_{B+i}\rangle^+_{B(L),\beta,h}/\langle n_{B+i}\rangle^+_{B(L),\beta,h}=\langle n_A\rangle^+_{\ast,\beta,h}$, where $\ast=B(L)-(B+i)$, now let $i, L$ tend to infinity the limit of the right hand side exists because $\ast$ converges to $\mathbb{Z}^d$ in the sense of Van Hove, now we use translation invariance gives what we need?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your identity. If you mean the following *inequality*, then yes, this seems a possible alternative. Let me write $C=B+i$, omit $\beta,h$ from the notation and write $\mathcal{F}_C$ for the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the spins in $C$.

Comment: Then, $\langle n_A n_C\rangle^+ = \langle n_C  \langle n_A \vert \mathcal{F}_C \rangle^+ \rangle^+ \leq \langle n_A \rangle_{\mathbb{Z}^d\setminus C}^+ \langle n_C \rangle^+ \leq \langle n_A \rangle_{\Lambda(i)}^+ \langle n_C \rangle^+$, where $\Lambda(i)$ is a cubic box centered at $0$ with a diameter at least, say, $\|i\|/10$ and $i$ is supposed to be so large that the latter box contains $A$ and that $C$ lies in its complement. Then, as $\|i\|\to\infty$, $\langle n_A \rangle_{\Lambda(i)}^+$ converges to $\langle n_A \rangle^+$ and you're done (if I have made no mistake).

Comment: $\langle n_An_{B+i}\rangle^+_{B(L),\beta,h}/\langle n_{B+i}\rangle^+_{B(L),\beta,h}$ is the probability of all spins in $A$ and $B+i$ be 1 divide over the probability of all spins in $B+i$ be 1, with the same boundary condition. After some cancellations, I think this gives the probability of all spins in $A$ be 1 with the modified boundary condition mentioned before?

Comment: You're right, I misread what you wrote. This indeed also works.